# How to align the text to center of cells in a QTableWidget

Tags: python, pyqt, alignment, pyqt4, qtablewidget

I am using PyQt based on Qt4. My Editor is PyCharm 2017.3 and my python version is 3.4. I am scraping some text from a website. I am trying to align that text to the center of the cell in a QTableWidget.

```
item = QTableWidgetItem(scraped_age).setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter)
self.tableWidget.setItem(x, 2,item)
```

Therefore while putting the item in the cell, I am trying to align it as per the [documentation](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qtablewidgetitem.html#setTextAlignment). The problem is that the data is not showing up.

[image: a part of QtableWidget where data is not showing up]

It did show up when I removed setTextAlignment method as shown below

```
item = QTableWidgetItem(scraped_age)
self.tableWidget.setItem(x, 2,item)
```

[image: a part of my QtableWidget]

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This line of code:

```
item = QTableWidgetItem(scraped_age).setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter)
```

will not work properly, because it throws away the item it creates before assigning it to the variable. The variable will in fact be set to `None`, which is the return value of `setTextAlignment()`. Instead, you must do this:

```
item = QTableWidgetItem(scraped_age) # create the item
item.setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter) # change the alignment
```

Comment: `Qt.AlignHCenter` will center horizontally at the top of the cell, `Qt.AlignCenter` will center to the center of the cell (horizontally and vertically).

Answer (score 11):

This didn't work for me, and I'm not sure if it is because I'm using PyQt5 or it i did something wrong. I was trying to find something similar but for the whole table, and i finally stumbled upon something that worked and lets you center every cells or just one column at a time.

You have to use the delegate method:

```
#You're probably importing QtWidgets to work with the table
#but you'll also need QtCore for the delegate class
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

class AlignDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def initStyleOption(self, option, index):
        super(AlignDelegate, self).initStyleOption(option, index)
        option.displayAlignment = QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter
```

After implementing this in your code, you can add the following to your main window class or wherever the table is defined:

```
delegate = AlignDelegate(self.tableWidget)
self.tableWidget.setItemDelegateForColumn(2, delegate) #You can repeat this line or
                                                       #use a simple iteration / loop
                                                       #to align multiple columns

 #If you want to do it for all columns:
 #self.tableWidget.setItemDelegate(delegate)
```

Know this is an old question, but hope it can help someone else.

Comment: When using AbstractTable model this delegate mechanism is a way better solution.

Answer (score 1):

Bit late to the party but for those of you wondering how to do this on pyqt5

```
table = QTableWidgetItem() #QTWidgets.QTableWidgetItem() if importing QWidget from PyQt5

table.setTextAlignment(number)
```

setTextAlignment takes an int for the argument (alignment). Put the number in to get the result:

0:left
1:left
2:right
3:right
4:centre

Answer (score 0):

If not using delegates and one doesn't want to set alignment for every `QTableWidgetItem` created anew, then you could *set the prototype item* in the table widget like so

```py
protoItem = QTableWidgetItem()
protoItem.setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
# set other things like read-only with QTableWidgetItem.setFlags, etc.

# set prototype item for all items created from now
myTableWidget.setItemPrototype(protoItem)
```